# Where to set java heap size for eclipse mars?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've installed eclipse mars in my Mac 10.9 machine. I frequently get OOM issue when doing some development in the eclipse. When i checked for the eclipse.ini file, i see `config.ini` file inside my `configuration` folder, which does not have any memory settings.
The config.ini file is like;

```
#This configuration file was written by: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.frameworkadmin.equinox.EquinoxFwConfigFileParser
#Mon Mar 16 14:23:27 IST 2015
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
eclipse.p2.profile=epp.package.jee
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/Documents/workspace
osgi.framework=file\:plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20140716-1347.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20140806-2000
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.0.v20131217-1203.jar@1\:start
```

Is this the file i need to edit and set for memory settings? or different?
    org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
    eclipse.product=org.eclipse.platform.ide
    osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/org.eclipse.platform
    osgi.framework.extensions=reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.100.v20140702-1948.jar
    osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
    eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
    eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add these lines in your eclipse.ini -

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar

org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m

-vmargs
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m

-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

Comment: I dont have eclipse.ini file. I see only config.ini file

Comment: Then add this while you run program in eclipse under VM arguments -
-Xmx 1024m

Comment: @Ratha You do have an eclipse.ini - it is inside the Eclipse.app package so you will have to use 'Show Package Contents' to see it in Finder.

Comment: The other answer by Rajesh seems more explanatory, which also highlights the fact that these arguments will be considered as VM arguments only if they are set following '-vmargs'.

Answer (score 7):

Please add the following VM args in eclipse.ini file and restart your eclipse.

-vmargs

-Xms512m

-Xmx1024m

The -Xms and -Xmx parameters define the minimum and maximum heap sizes, respectively. Here we're setting the max heap size as 1GB. That can be increased based on your RAM size